# Is there a library similar to ERC-165, In OpenBrush or Ink smart contracts, used to identify the implemented interfaces of a smart contract?

Tags: ink, openbrush

"I'm working on developing smart contracts using OpenBrush and the Ink programming language, and I'm in need of a mechanism to detect and identify the interfaces that a particular smart contract implements. In the Ethereum ecosystem, ERC-165 provides a standard way to do this, as detailed in this [EIP section](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165#how-interfaces-are-identified).

However, I'm looking for a solution that is specifically tailored to OpenBrush and Ink smart contracts. Is there a library or a recommended approach for achieving interface detection in this context? I'm keen to find a solution that is compatible with these technologies and offers similar functionality to ERC-165.

Any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Answer (score 1):

It's part of OpenBrush, check this PR:

https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/pull/112